# Large Reference Data

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

In my Azure Streaming Analytics job, I am attempting to geolocate IP Addresses. The reference that I am using is around 165 MB.  Reference Data blobs are limited to 100 MB each, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-use-reference-data) states the following:

> Stream Analytics has a limit of 100 MB per blob but jobs can process multiple reference blobs by using the path pattern property.

How would I go about taking advantage of this?  I have split my data into two 85 MB files, `iplookup1.csv` and `iplookup2.csv` but do not seem to be able to figure out how to get the Reference Data input to pick up both as a large dataset.

As a stop-gap, I may try to create two reference data inputs, then do a left-join across both and pull the value that is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, for reference data you could specify the static data (e.g. `products/products.csv`) in the Path Pattern property or you could specify one or more instances of those variables (`{date}`, `{time}`) like `products/{date}/{time}/products.csv` to refresh your reference data.

Based on your scenario, I assumed that you need to create two reference data inputs, then you could leverage the [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn835008.aspx) operation for combining the results of two or more queries into a single result. For Reference Data JOIN, you could follow [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Dn949258.aspx).

**UPDATE:**

```html
SELECT I1.propertyName, ip01.propertyName
    FROM Input1 I1
    JOIN iplookup1 ip01  
    ON I1.address= ip01.address

UNION

SELECT I1.propertyName, ip02.propertyName
    FROM Input1 I1
    JOIN iplookup2 ip02  
    ON I1.address= ip02.address
```

Comment: Great suggestion!  I gave it a try, but am receiving an error stating that `Union is not supported on reference data`

Comment: I updated my answer with the sample query, you could refer to it.